# Using results of If-Then statement in true clause

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to use the value that returned true later on in an equation but am finding it difficult, if not impossible, to do so.  This is what my formula looks like:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Application","Account","Machine"}, H5))),
    INDEX(Sheet1!N$2:N$7, 
    MATCH(<term that made the SEARCH function true,Sheet1!M$2:M$7,0)), "")
```

I am trying to search a cell for a series of words, and if one of those words is found, use that word in an INDEX-MATCH search. Is there a way to do this or do I need to break my work up into two steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are after this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!N:N, MATCH(
   INDEX({"Application","Account","Machine"},
   MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Application","Account","Machine"},H5)),0)),
 Sheet1!M:M,0)), "")
```

Note that the inner `INDEX/MATCH` is what you were looking for, that is, returns from the array the keyword that exists inside the `H5` sentence.

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm!  I'm going to need to save this equation for the future, both for learning and for the next time something like this comes up!

Comment: @Tchotchke Glad to know that :-). Also keep in mind that the hard-coded keywords arrays can be easily replaced by a range. So if it grows in the future, a good design solution would be to move it to a range.